# Force JSF to bean-validate ALL fields of my bean, not only those bound to an input field

Tags: jsf, input, field, bean-validation

I am working with the Apache MyFaces Core 2.1 library and Hibernate Validator 5. I have a simple JavaBean with some annotations. My form with some input fields map to this JavaBean. However, if I annotate a field with a constraint (e.g. @NotNull or @Min(value = 1000)) but do not use a input field in the form, the fields of the JavaBean are valid. Can I force the JSF lifecycle to validate ALL fields of may JavaBean, not only those with an input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot. The integration of JSF with Bean Validation uses *Validator.validateValue* to validate each input field on its own. It is not using *Validator.validate* in order to validate the whole bean.

If you really want the full bean evaluated you need to do it on another layer (eg JPA if you are using it).